# mysqli_real_escape_string mysqli link?

Tags: php, mysqli

I get "Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp\www\Game\functions.php on line 8"   when trying to use the function, here's the code.

```
function protect($string) {
return mysqli_real_escape_string($con,strip_tags(addslashes($string)));
}
```

I use the $con for my queries and it's fine so I thought that was what was for this mysqli part?

This is for registration, I have some registration that is working but I can't use that, here's a confirmed working line

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string needs a connection BEFORE it can function,use global $con; as the first line in your function.

Comment: Using just "global $con;" worked, thanks!

Comment: @mihai How do I choose it as answer? lol

Comment: Post it as your own answer and accept it after a couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSWER FROM MIHAI

mysqli_real_escape_string needs a connection BEFORE it can function,use global $con; as the first line in your function. –  Mihai

Answer (score 2):

`$con` doesn't exist in the function `protect()`, so you either need to make `$con` global:

```
global $con = mysqli_connect();
```

or you need to pass `$con` as an argument:

```
function protect($string, $con) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($con,strip_tags(addslashes($string)));
}
```

Comment: I have "$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");" in a connect.php file with "Include('connect.php');" but still doesn't work :(